Run a command inside a WSL environment using python
I'm attempting to open a CMD, followed by launching WSL and executing some scripts within it. Initially, I'm aiming to print a 'hello world' message inside the WSL environment. However, I'm encountering an issue where the message isn't printed, and no further commands are executed after launching WSL with the '-d Ubuntu' flag.
import subprocess

batch_content = f"""
@echo off
d:
cd Ubuntu\\OpenSfM
wsl -d Ubuntu 
"echo 'hello world'"
cmd /k 
"""

batch_file_path = 'run_wsl.bat'
with open(batch_file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write(batch_content)

subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'start', batch_file_path])

